# List<T> from property in List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I wasn't able to find much about how to do this. I'm probably not getting the terminology right.

I have a list of objects:

```
class Cat()
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();

cats.add(new Cat() { Name = "Felix" } );
cats.add(new Cat() { Name = "Fluffy" } );
```

How do I get a list of strings from the Name property so it looks like this:

```
{ "Felix", "Fluffy" }
```

Comment: Are you trying to serialize the list to JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var names = cats.Select(c => c.Name);
```

But if you still need a list use

```
List<string> names = cats.ConvertAll(c => c.Name);
```

Comment: Omg, thanks all for the super quick responses. I can't believe it's this simple *face palm*. Yuriy, thanks for the Linq-less way to do it!

Answer (score 9):

The LINQ [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357126.aspx) operator is your friend:

```
cats.Select(c => c.Name).ToList()
```

I am using `ToList()` to avoid lazy evaluation and to ensure you have an `IList` to work with.

Answer (score 2):

cats.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()

Answer (score 2):

```
cats.Select(cat => cat.Name).ToList();
```

or

```
(from cat in cats select cat.Name).ToList();
```

If you don't actually need the `List` as an output, you can leave off the `.ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allowed (or don't want to) use var, extension methods and Linq or need a list of strings:

```
List<string> names = cats.ConvertAll(cat => cat.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = (from cat in cats
             select cat.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

using linq:

```
var names = cats.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listOfNames = (from c in cats
                   select c.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cats.Select(e => e.Name).ToArray();
```

Im pretty new with LINQ so I dont guarntee that works.

Also, add System.Linq namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cats.Select(cat => cat.Name).ToList()
```